# Python How to send email without having this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I have included the screenshot of output. Please help me solve this issue. [image: Screenshot]

**input**

```
import smtplib
conn = smtplib.SMTP('imap.gmail.com',587)
conn.ehlo()
conn.starttls()
conn.login('example@gmail.com', 'password')

conn.sendmail('example@gmail.com','emaple2@gmail.com','Subject: What you like? \n\n Reply Reply Reply')
conn.quit()
```

**output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\openCV\email.py", line 3, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Users\loges\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "E:\python\openCV\email.py", line 4, in <module>
    conn = smtplib.SMTP('imap.gmail.com',587)
AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP'
```

Comment: The original problem was solved. You should have accepted my answer and posted another question. As the error message suggests, your mail server is not responding.

Comment: Please do not post images of error messages. Copy them as text and put in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is called `email.py`. A standard Python library module with the same name is used by `smtplib`. As a result, `smtplib` imports *your* file instead of the standard module. Solution: rename your file.